# LWO import in 2.7x ( macOS) ?

Tags: import, osx

I don't see Lightwave object in import menu and I was wondering if the support has been dropped. I still see the python script for lwo format in addons folder, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried from 2.79 to 2.70,versions work on current macOS (Sierra). 2.69 won't launch under current OS. I don't have a PC to test it.

Thanks in advance.

Euisung Lee

Comment: Alternative is to export fbx from LW then import fbx into Blender which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open the System Preferences (ctrl+Alt+U) and in the addon section enable the **Import Lightwave Objects Addon**

[image]

An option to import LWO will appear on the file menu.

[image]